# JSF 2 -- Get instance of a PhaseListener from a managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, phaselistener

Is there a way to get the current instance of a PhaseListener via el context or application context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the phase listeners attached to the UIViewRoot using `<f:phaseListener>` tag on a page like this:

```
List<PhaseListener> phaseListeners = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getPhaseListeners();
```

It returns a list of the PhaseListener instances attached to this UIViewRoot instance.

If you want to get all the global phase listeners registered in a faces-config.xml file you can get them from the LifeCycle instance like this:

```
FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory)FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);    
LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory)FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
Iterator<String> lifecycleIds = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycleIds(); 
while (lifecycleIds.hasNext()) { 
    String lifecycleId = lifecycleIds.next(); 
    Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(lifecycleId);
    PhaseListener[] phaseListeners= lifecycle.getPhaseListeners();
}
```

[Documentation UIViewRoot](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getPhaseListeners%28%29)

[Documentation LifeCycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#getPhaseListeners%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the current PhaseID in JSF 2.0 with:

```
PhaseId currentPhaseId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId();
```

Comment: You're not answering the question. The OP is asking how to get the currently registered `PhaseListener`s, not how to get the current phase ID, which is indeed way too obvious.